# How to give docker access to path with mysql database?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem. I have created my docker-compose and in it one of the service has a script written in python to backup the mysql database locally. I don't know how to make the script in the docker access the path '/var/lib/mysql/' on the host. To backup database I use:

```
subprocess.check_call(f"mysqldump -u phpmyadmin -pMyPassword MyDatabase > /var/lib/mysql/backups/MyDatabase/26_09_2022.sql.backup")
```

Could you help me? Should I use volume?

Comment: Does the mysql database let you access it over a TCP port? If so that can be used to dump the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use volume?

Yes, volumes are the answer. Based on your example, it should look like this.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  your_service:
    ...other_config...
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Or written out like this.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  your_service:
    ...other_config...
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /var/lib/mysql
        target: /var/lib/mysql
```